# Why creating a Gradle project downloading gradle.zip from Internet?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have installed Gradle plugin on my Eclipse(STS) and downloaded gradle.zip and configured to use gradle.zip from my local filesystem in Gradle Preferences page. But when I create a Gradle project it is still trying to download gradle.zip from Internet.

In my corporate environment URLs like .zip and .rar are blocked, so when it tries to download it got failed. 
Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: Configure Eclipse not to use gradle wrapper even if present?

Comment: In Windows->Preferences->Gradle menu, I have changed Gradle Distribution option to Folder and gave my local gradle directory path. But still it is trying to download from internet resulting "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.0-rc-2-all.zip" error.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you more, I use IDEA...

Answer (score 0):

Oh..it seems problem with eclipse-gradle plugin. I installed Gradle plugin on NetbeansIDE-7.3.1 and set Gradle home path to my local Gradle directory and working fine.

Comment: Aah..this problem is resolved in STS-3.5.1 and again getting the same issue with STS-3.6.3. Crap!